# Subset pairs of repeated elements from a list

Tags: r, string, list, raster

I am trying to subset a list with repeated files by year. This could be easily address if the files had the same name, but this is not the case.

The list is the following:

```
 dput(list_raster)
    c("F101992.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F101993.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F101994.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F121994.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F121995.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F121996.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F121997.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F121998.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F121999.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F141997.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F141998.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F141999.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F142000.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F142001.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F142002.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F142003.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F152000.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F152001.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F152002.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F152003.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F152004.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F152005.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F152006.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F152007.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F152008.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F162004.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F162005.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F162006.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F162007.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F162008.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F162009.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F182010.v4d_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F182011.v4c_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F182012.v4c_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
    "F182013.v4c_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif")
```

As you can see there are several year-files repeated `(i.e. 1994, 1997-1999, 2000-2003, etc.)`. My idea was to construct a list with pairs of repeated year-files to mean their values using the `raster::overlay` function. I have tried the following:

```
    library(stringr)  
    #Create a list of only the years of the files
    year_list <- lapply(list_raster, str_sub, 4, 7)
    #Select the duplicate years
    duplicated_years <- year_list[duplicated(year_list)]
    #Select the duplicate file-years
    duplicated_rasters <- list_raster[lapply(list_raster, str_sub, 4, 7) %in% duplicated_years]
    #Make all the pairs between files
    duplicated_rasters <- combn(duplicated_rasters, 2, simplify=T)
```

Nonetheless, I now have a matrix with lot of pairs and I am kind of stuck making a selection of repeated years. There ir a simple way to do this? I think my inexperience is making me "overcode" this.

Comment: Please submit a minimal reproducible example. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Specifically you should share your (minimal reproducible) data using `dput()`

Comment: Hello Eric, the list of strings `list_raster` is my "data". I only want to select the duplicates by year of this list.

Comment: What Eric means is execute dput(list_raster) and paste the output in your question so that it makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand the advice. Thanks Eric and andrnev.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `by` here to apply a function(`overlay` in occurence) by group of years. Of course you should first extract the year from the file names:

```
 by(xx,INDICES=substr(xx,4,7),FUN = function(x)## function body)
```

Where xx is your files list:

```
  dput(head(xx))
c("F101992.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F101993.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
"F101994.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F121994.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", 
"F121995.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif", "F121996.v4b_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif"
)
```

Comment: by() does not seems to work. It display an error: `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘overlay’ for signature ‘"factor", "missing"’`.